# Taskbar Window Order changing in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

In Windows 7,  I have the “Never combine” option of the taskbar selected.  (I'm using [this hack](http://www.windows7news.com/2009/08/26/add-never-combine-hide-labels-to-the-windows-7-taskbar/) to remove the text from the icons, but I dont think this has much of an impact on my issue.)

I tend to put my laptop to sleep every night and sometimes when I reopen the laptop the next morning my two firefox windows order have changed (I've noticed this with other applications--I think Word and Excel--but it's much more rare with them and the windows I have open in these apps varies much more).  This isn't a huge deal, but it interrupts my flow as I usually have personal tabs in the window on the left and work-related tabs open in the window on the right.

Anyone know what could be changing this order?

If I close the application it will open again in the new switched order (ie, it doesn't change things back).

Comment: Guessing here, but it could be the way Explorer comes out of sleep mode, and possibly crashing and reloading?

Comment: Does the taskbar restart when Explorer crashes?

Comment: It can do under certain circumstances.

Comment: Coincidentally, this just happened to the outlook windows I have open--they reversed order.